# Is there a way to get facebook public info from name?

Tags: facebook

IS there a way that if I provide name and/or company name I get the user's facebook details

Eg : If I enter a name as "John Dropes" I get all related public info(Eg : Birthday,Location etc) of all users with this name.

I am not going to use Facebook Username or ID I should be able to get info just from name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the search to get a list of users:

```
/search?q=John%20Doe&type=user
```

This will return a list of users which match the name more or less closely:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "John Doe", 
      "id": "7688817164415"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Rubén Doe", 
      "id": "3650636703421"
    }, 
    ...
   ]
}
```

You can then issue request to the `id` of the individual users:

```
/7688817164415
```

This will give you some info. But be aware that the standard info set is very narrow.