# How to get user likes and other public data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get Facebook public data such as users and groups using the search functionality in graph API. I used long live tokens and also I have granted permissions for my app. Till now, for searching based on user details, I am only able to get the following.

1. User Name
2. User Id

For groups and pages:

1. Id of group or page
2. Name of group
3. Category.

But although I have granted permissions in my access token I am unable to get data such as "likes", "comments" etc. Its showing empty data set. How should I proceed so that I can get these information ?

Comment: before asking any questions, at least read basic documentation

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood how the permissions work. With an access token, you can only query the detailed information for the user which "created" the access token by giving his permission to use the set of his data.

This is not at all valid for all other Facebook users.

Comment: Ok.. I understood .Is there any other way by which I can get user's public data .? Can You please help me with this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242546/is-there-a-way-to-get-facebook-public-info-from-name/27244900#27244900